# Suppose a $3\times{5}$ matrix $A$ has three pivot columns, what is the dimension of the Null space?

Tags: linear-algebra

The question is as follow: " Suppose a $3\times{5}$ matrix $A$ has three pivot columns, what is the dimension of the Null space? "

I think the answer have to be $2$ .

There are $3$ pivot columns so that means that there are $2$ columns left with free variables.

The answer of the questions is apperantly 5. I dont know why and i am wondering if the answer is wrong and mine is correct. They say that the Dim of the Nulspace is in R5 because the vectors are in R5

Can someone tell me what is correct?

Thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The dimension of the nullspace is $2$. You are right, and the given answer is wrong.

The nullspace is a subspace of $\Bbb R^5$, and as such the elements of said nullspace is most naturally described using $5\times 1$ column vectors. However, that doesn't mean the space has dimension $5$.